# Ubuntu in VMware - not able to enter password to login

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, passwords, password-management, ubuntu-10.04

I installed Ubuntu 10 on VMware 7.0 for learning purposes, but I am not able to enter a  password in order to log in.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: do you know what the password is?

Comment: Are Caps Lock or Num Lock on?

Answer (score 3):

This issue was already covered here:

[Ubuntu 10.04 doesn't accept keyboard input when running under VMware on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/136874/ubuntu-10-04-doesnt-accept-keyboard-input-when-running-under-vmware-on-windows)

See that last post for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try have the window in focus and press CTRL+ALT+F2 and try log in through the CLI, if that works you can then start Xorg by issuing the startx command, hopefully this works. I have never tried VMWare myself, only VirtualBox, and there it works withouth any problems.